# JQuery - Set Person Field Value

Tags: sharepoint-designer, list, javascript, jquery, person-or-group

How to set person field on form load and save the field value when item saves. I have added following code in script editor web part `NewForm.aspx`. But this is not working. Appreciate your support.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("div[title='Assigned To']").val("i:0#.w|domain\user");
});
```

Comment: Try using the solution given [here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/people-picker-field-actions-in-sharepoint-using-javascript-jsom/) and let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

Try using below code:

```
//Display name of your field
var fAssignedTo = "Assigned To";  

$(document).ready(function(){  
     BindPeoplePickerWithLoggedinUser(fAssignedTo);  
});

function BindPeoplePickerWithLoggedinUser(ppTitle){  
    setTimeout(function(){  
        var _PeoplePicker = $("div[title='" + ppTitle + "']");  
        var peoplePickerEditor = _PeoplePicker.find("[title='" + ppTitle + "']");  
        var _PeoplePickerTopId = _PeoplePicker.attr('id');

        //This is setting the value to current logged in user
        peoplePickerEditor.val(_spPageContextInfo.userDisplayName);  
        var ppobject = SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict[_PeoplePickerTopId];         
        ppobject.AddUnresolvedUserFromEditor(true);  
    }, 1000);      
}
```

**Reference**:

1. [People Picker Field Actions In SharePoint Using JavaScript (JSOM)](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/people-picker-field-actions-in-sharepoint-using-javascript-jsom/).

Comment: It's not working for me.

Comment: Are you getting any error in console? Are you passing the field name correctly?

Comment: I don't get any error in console. Field name is correct

Comment: Strange. This is working for me and I was able to add the list item. Are you passing the current logged in user (same as given in my answer)?

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc('clientpeoplepicker.js', 'SPClientPeoplePicker', function ()
{
    var neededPeoplePicker = SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict[GiveTheIndexHere];
    var usrObj = { 'Key': 'i:0#.w|domain\user' };
    neededPeoplePicker.AddUnresolvedUser(usrObj, true);
})
```

Adding my complete code below.
The requirement was to auto-populate L1, L2, L3 managers based on the user name added to the 'Process Owner' field.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    SP.SOD.executeFunc('clientpeoplepicker.js', 'SPClientPeoplePicker', function ()
    {
        var processOwnerFieldIdProcessOwner = $("div[title='Process Owner']").attr('id');

        SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict[processOwnerFieldIdProcessOwner].OnControlValidateClientScript = function (peoplePickerId, selectedUsersInfo)
        {
            console.log('inside OnValueChangedClientScript');
            var processOwnerFieldUserInfoJson = SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict[processOwnerFieldIdProcessOwner].GetAllUserInfo();

            if(processOwnerFieldUserInfoJson.length > 0 )
            {
                var processOwnerFieldUserId = processOwnerFieldUserInfoJson["0"].AutoFillKey;
                processOwnerFieldUserId = encodeURIComponent(processOwnerFieldUserId);
                console.log(processOwnerFieldUserId);
                getManagersOfUser(processOwnerFieldUserId);
            }
        };


        function getManagersOfUser(processOwnerFieldUserId)
        {
            $.ajax({

            url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetPropertiesFor(accountName=@v)?@v='"+processOwnerFieldUserId+"'",

            method: "GET",

            headers:
                {  
                    "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                    "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose"
                },  

            success: function(data)
                {  
                    console.log(data);
                    populateL1L2L3Managers(data.d.ExtendedManagers.results);
                },

            error: function(error)
                {  
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(error));  
                }  
            })
        }       


        function populateL1L2L3Managers(managersArray)
        {   
            var counter = 1;
            for(var i = managersArray.length-1; i> managersArray.length-4 && i >= 0;i--)
            {
                console.log(managersArray[i]);
                //debugger;
                var peoplePickerName;

                if(counter == 1)
                {
                    peoplePickerName = "L1_x0020_Manager";
                }
                else if(counter == 2)
                {
                    peoplePickerName = "L2_x0020_Manager";
                }
                else if(counter == 3)
                {
                    peoplePickerName = "L3_x0020_Manager";
                }

                counter++;

                try
                {
                        var travelPeoplePicker = null;
                        for (var prop in SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict)
                        {

                            if (prop.indexOf(peoplePickerName) >= 0)
                            {
                                travelPeoplePicker = SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict[prop];
                                break;
                            }
                        }

                        if (travelPeoplePicker != null)
                        {
                            travelPeoplePicker.DeleteProcessedUser();

                            var usrObj = { 'Key': managersArray[i] };
                            travelPeoplePicker.AddUnresolvedUser(usrObj, true);
                        }
                    }
                    catch (e)
                    {
                        //alert(e);
                    }       
            }       
        }



    });
});
```